# Converting names to proper format

Tags: excel, vba

I often get names in which I need to work with and reconcile some of their information. These names would often come in many different formats. The current VBA script I've got on is as follows:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Or Target.HasFormula Then Exit Sub
    On Error Resume Next
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B:B")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Target.Value = StrConv(Target.Value, vbProperCase)
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

It does the trick with changing names to Proper case but I'm also hoping to automate capitalized names that has the surname in the front, separated with a comma (e.g. SMITH, JOHN).

In researching, I have found the following formula to work brilliantly, but this is not in VBA - I need it to auto convert the same cell:

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-LEN(LEFT(A1,FIND(",",A1)-1))-2) & " " & LEFT(A1,FIND(",",A1)-1)
```

Would there be anyway if I could have this formula functioning in the VBA script?

Lastly, it would amaze me if this script could recognize specialized surnames, especially capitalize the letter after a symbol (e.g. Mary-Lee / O'Connor).

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may be interested in the [Proper](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-proper-function) function.

Comment: @Vegard I'm actually after a VBA script as I wanted to a cell update rather than a function in another cell.

Comment: You [can use Worksheet functions in VBA](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/convert-to-proper-case.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I converted your worksheet formula to VBA, you can use INSTR to get the same result as FIND, the arguments are passed to it in the opposite order but apart from that its the same. (I made a string called A1 to make it easier to compare to your example)

```
    Dim A1 As String
    A1 = Target.Value

    If (InStr(A1, ",") > 0) Then
        Target.Value = Right(A1, Len(A1) - Len(Left(A1, InStr(A1, ",") - 1)) - 2) & " " & Left(A1, InStr(A1, ",") - 1)
    End If
```

This will capitalise the next character after an apostrophe, you can edit it to handle other punctuation

```
Dim A1 As String
A1 = Target.Value

Dim i As Integer
i = InStr(A1, "'") 'position of the '

If (i > 0 And Len(A1) > i) Then 'check there is a ' present and there is a character after it
    Target.Value = Left(A1, i) & UCase(Mid(A1, i + 1, 1)) & Right(A1, Len(A1) - i - 1)
End If
```

Comment: thank you for your help! I'm a newbie here, how would I be able to add additional punctuation arguments, such as Jamie-Lee McDonald, while keeping the existing Peter O'Connor?

Comment: One more thing, would I be able to restrict this function to column B only (or B1:B1000)? Due to the other formulas I have on the spreadsheet, it seems to be freezing the worksheet as is.

Comment: If you want to implement handling of the hyphen i.e. make sure every character directly following a hyphen is a capital all you need to do is take that second chunk of code I provided and replace the apostrophe with a hyphen i.e. i = InStr(A1, "-") 'position of the -

Comment: Doesn't your original function only operate on column B by means of this line: "If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B:B")) Is Nothing Then" If so you just need to add the chunks of code I've provided after this line : "Target.Value = StrConv(Target.Value, vbProperCase)" and you should be done. You'll have to edit it slightly as you'll be declaring A1 multiple times if you just copy it verbatim

Answer (score 1):

Add just before you `Application.EnableEvents = True` line:

```
If InStr(Target.Value, ",") > 0 Then
    Target.Value = UCase(Left(Target.Value, InStr(Target.Value, ",") - 1)) & Mid(Target.Value, InStr(Target.Value, ","), Len(Target.Value))
End If
```

NB:  Add `With Target` as your first line of code and `End With` as your last and change all your `Target.Value` references to just `.Value`.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx